# In my bot application getting error while adding assembly reference to "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs"

Tags: c#, .net, bots

Getting an error in adding assembly reference to "Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs" that Type or namespace name Builder does not exist in the namespace "Microsoft.Bot".

I have added the reference to "Microsoft.Bot.Builder" but still I am getting this error in Using statement.

Please suggest what could be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the using statement can't find the referenced assembly. So, you need to add either a project reference or assembly dll reference. If you have access to the code and want to debug the referenced code, then you should add a project reference.

To add a project reference, first you have to add the Microsoft.Bot.Builder project to your solution. It looks like the project code can be downloaded from this [link](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder).

Once you have downloaded the code, the project can be added to your solution by right clicking on the solution name in Visual Studio Solution Explorer and then selecting Add / Existing Project.

After the project has been added to your solution, a project reference can then be added by by right clicking on references (under your project), selecting Add, then click on projects, and then double click on the project you just added.

If instead you don't think you will want to debug and step through the bot code, then you can add a dll assembly reference. Make sure that you have the latest version of the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs dll. Right click on references from Visual Studio Solution Explorer. Select Browse and then navigate to the folder where the dll is located. If you believe the assembly you wish to reference has been installed, then you can click on Assemblies instead and click on the appropriate assembly.

For more info on references, see this [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx).

Comment: @VaijinathHarbak Then please edit your question to include the code that fails to compile.